# threejs how to make points have orientation

Tags: three.js, 3d

I want to realize a points system on globe that points facing on the center of the globe, right now i am using circleGeometry, it is good in visualization. But if  I want to generate and remove points in a large scale. All the circleGeometries will be recalculated. The performance is not so good. Before I tried to use bufferGeometry and points to realize. Then all the points always facing camera when for points there is no orientation.

So what can I do now? Is there some other methods I can have a try?Thank you so much for your help.

corresponding code(using circleGeometry):

```
for (var city in Data) {
var result = returnSphericalCoordinates(
      Data[city].y,
      Data[city].x
);

sizes[city] = 3* Math.pow(Data[city].numPoints,1/2);
var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( sizes[city]/2, 32 );
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('./disc.png')
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
map: texture,
transparent:true,
alphaTest: 0.2,
side: THREE.DoubleSide,
depthWrite: false
// antialias: true 
});
this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
this.mesh.position.set(result.x, result.y, result.z );
this.mesh.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
```

Points system I was trying to use:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
geometry.addAttribute( 'size', new THREE.BufferAttribute( sizes, 1 ) );
geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

  // Make texture
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('./disc.png')
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

ShaderLoader('./pointshader.vert',
'./pointshader.frag',
function(vertex,fragment){
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
uniforms: {
texture: {value : texture},
color: {value : new THREE.Color(0xffffff)}
},
vertexShader: vertex,
fragmentShader: fragment,
side: THREE.DoubleSide,
transparent: true,
alphaTest: 0.05,
// depthWrite: false
} );
this.globeDots = new THREE.(geometry, material);
this.globeDots.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
this.globeDots.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
props.threeObject.add(this.globeDots);
// })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGKmi.png)

Comment: What do you mean with "All the circleGeometries will be recalculated"? Is it possible for you to share a link to your application?

Comment: Because it is a part inside a project, So I can not share the application right now, but what i am trying to do is to realize marker_cluster on 3D globe(like leaflet marker_cluster), so the points with be clustered and distributed according to the zoom level.

Comment: Okay, I see. But what about your statement "All the circleGeometries will be recalculated"? I'd like to point out the following: If the geometry of your circles/markers is actually static, you might want to use instanced rendering in order to reduce the amount of draw calls.

Comment: ok, I think I will try this instanced rendering way first to check the performance. Thank you a lot!